# Laravel using Excel package inside controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to use `Excel:  @package maatwebsite/excel` package on laravel inside controller, but i get this error:

```
Non-static method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create() 
should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

**my route is:**

```
Route::get('all_users_report/{format}', 'SystemExportDataController@all_users_report');
```

**my controller is:**

```
class SystemExportDataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $format
     */
    public function all_users_report($format)
    {
        Excel::create('all_users_records', function ($excel) use ($format) {
            $excel->sheet('My Site - all users report', function ($sheet) use ($format) {
                ........
            });
        })->export($format);
    }
}
```

**POST UPDATED 2**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider'
],
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Excel'     => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel'
],
```

**Error:**

```
BadMethodCallException in ServiceProvider.php line 234: 
Call to undefined method [package]
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Full Class Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

class SystemExportDataController extends Controller
{
    public function all_users_report($format)
    {
        Excel::create('all_users_records', function ($excel) use ($format) {
            $excel->sheet('Epay.Li - all users report', function ($sheet) use ($format) {
                $all_records = ChangeMoney::all();
                $sheet->loadView('layouts.admin.all_users_report',
                    array(
                        'all_records' => $all_records,
                    )
                );
            });
        })->export($format);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel` not `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;` when you are calling static method like `Excel::create()`

Answer (score 2):

You should add `'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel'` to your facades array in `config/app.php` and `'Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel\ServiceProvider'` to your providers in order to use it the way you do.

Or you can make an instance of the class using `$excel = App::make('excel');` and then `$excel->create(...`.

**UPDATE**

There are two ways to call the Excel package:

One of them is to use the facade, but you have to add `'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel'` in your facades array in `config/app.php` and then

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;

class SystemExportDataController extends Controller
{
    public function all_users_report($format)
    {
        Excel::create('all_users_records', function ($excel) use ($format) {
            $excel->sheet('Epay.Li - all users report', function ($sheet) use ($format) {
                $all_records = ChangeMoney::all();
                $sheet->loadView('layouts.admin.all_users_report',
                    array(
                        'all_records' => $all_records,
                    )
                );
            });
        })->export($format);
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the second `use`. Also if you don't want to add the facade in the facades array, you could use it - `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel`.

The other way is to make an instance of the package and use that instance, like this:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SystemExportDataController extends Controller
{
    public function all_users_report($format)
    {
        $excel = App::make('excel');
        $excel->create('all_users_records', function ($excel) use ($format) {
            $excel->sheet('Epay.Li - all users report', function ($sheet) use ($format) {
                $all_records = ChangeMoney::all();
                $sheet->loadView('layouts.admin.all_users_report',
                    array(
                        'all_records' => $all_records,
                    )
                );
            });
        })->export($format);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post but if you'd like to use the facade, you should just add it, along with the providers in `config/app.php` and that's it. No need to make a new instance :)

Comment: Have you installed version 2 of the package? `composer require maatwebsite/excel:2.*` and please run `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: thanks, please let me to install and test that sir, Thanks

Comment: oh sir. i get error :( `Non-static method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context` i paste full class controller

Comment: I'm sorry sir, i get error `Class excel does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

I have found I need to prepend a backslash (signifies the [root namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)) to make sure it's using the Facade. This would make your call as follows:

```
\Excel::create('all_users_records', function ($excel) use ($format) {
    $excel->sheet('Epay.Li - all users report', function ($sheet) use ($format) {
        $all_records = ChangeMoney::all();
        $sheet->loadView('layouts.admin.all_users_report',
            array(
                'all_records' => $all_records,
            )
        );
    });
})->export($format);
```